# How to implement OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow between Angular (Front-End) and Spring Boot (at Back-End) using Azure AD

Tags: azure, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to implement OAuth 2.0 authorization code Grant between Angular (Front-End) and Spring Boot (at Back-End) using Azure AD. I am unable to get any success. I have looked into the documentations available in Azure Doc. There are no samples with Angular in Front End and Spring Boot in Back End. Any suggestions would help.

Comment: please see: https://ordina-jworks.github.io/security/2020/08/18/Securing-Applications-Azure-AD.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Carl for the help. You are a life saver :-)

Comment: I'm so happy for you, I will post it as an answer, hoping to help more people.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [document](https://ordina-jworks.github.io/security/2020/08/18/Securing-Applications-Azure-AD.html), which uses Angular as the front-end, Spring Boot as the back-end, and uses [OAuth 2.0 auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to grant authentication.